# Right way to get a value

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript and I have a doubt about the effective and cleanest way to get the correct value of an object, example:

```
function Group(cod, teacher) {
    this.cod = cod;
    this.teacher = teacher;
}
```

In other languages ​​usually use a function to get a value, example:

```
Group.prototype.getCod = function() {
    return this.cod;
}
```

But everything is very flexible in javascript, I can get this value with the name in the code, example:

```
var group = new Group(5, 'Max');
var cod = group['cod']; // 5
```

Now... What is the right way??

Comment: *"What is the right way??"* It is what you think the right way is.

Comment: All depends on you. Using a function is great for encapsulating, but maybe you need a setter? Newer javascript allows you to define getter/setter, but maybe they shouldn't have access at all (except as an outcome of another function). --All your choice.

Comment: If you create a function `getCod` you may consider to put `cod` variable and not expose it directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of the following ways works fine:

```
group['cod'];
group.cod; //the most common way as far as I percieve is this
group.getCod();
```

have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/txwgp92t/).

I set your `getCod()` function without `new`!

```
Group.prototype.getCod = function() {
    return this.cod;
}
```

---

**The following is opinion based!**

IMHO you can use syntax depending on the use case.

I would use `group['cod']` syntax for arrays only, as it is common notation in other languages.

Most of the time, I would use `group.cod` notation for attribute access, as it is sort of the most common notation - with the exception of

the `group.getCod()` notation. Getters are useful, if fetching the value implies other actions as well. Consider this example:

```
Group.prototype.getCod = function() {
    this.codCount--;
    return this.cod;
}
```

Comment: Edited :), you are right. Thanks.